# class is public, should be decl

Tags: java, class, intellij-idea, error-handling, ide

"java: class FirstProgram is public, should be declared in a file name FirstProgram.java" error. My class and file names match, which is why i am confused. Screenshot of what I see on my IDE, along with copy and pasted code and error message are posted below. Thank you for your time.

```
public class FirstProgram
{
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
System.out.println("Programming is not a spectator sport");
  System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Error:(4, 8) java: class FirstProgram is public, should be declared in a file named FirstProgram.java

[IDE Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6ytS.png)

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is you named the class main, the name of the program, even the file name, must match the name of the class. Your class name is Firstprogram but your file name is main. You must change the file name to Firstprogram.java

Comment: You can see on the screenshot the name of the project is FirstProgram.java which matches the "public class FirstProgram". Is this not right?

Comment: I am seeing that it is says main.java underneath it, I am not familar with that ide but that is what led to conclude that he named the class main.java not Firstprogram.java

Comment: Also it appears he named the host file FIrstProgram.java but maybe named the class something main.java, if this is some form of intellij then when he created the class object he did not name it correctly.